# Uab marking of voltage difference betwen two nodes?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

If I say \$U_{AB}\$, point \$A\$ will be point on higher potential, right? 
Because \$U_{AB}=U_A-U_B\$?

Comment: If you say \$U_{ab}\$ is positive, then it means A is at a higher potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Uab convention rises form "Line integrals" in electrostatics, now if you have recently taken any multi-variable or vector calculus classes you might be familiar with the concept of taking line integrals in a force field:

[image]

Small contributions of this force field to the movement of your charge will define the potential from A to B.

- Now if the E field is supporting the motion of your charge Uab is positive(+)
  $$U_{ab}=\int_a^b \vec{E}.\vec{ds}$$
- If E field is opposing the motion of your charge Uab will be negative(-)

$$U_{ba}=\int_a^b \vec{-E}.\vec{ds}=-\int_a^b \vec{E}.\vec{ds}=\int_b^a \vec{E}.\vec{ds}=-U_{ab}$$

Answer (score 2):

If \$U_{ab}\$ is positive, then A is at a higher potential than B.

Comment: Then, if i say Uab = -2 (v), that means that point b is on higher potential than a?

Comment: @Jovana, yes, and if point B is at a higher potential than A, then it also means point A is at a lower potential than B.